# en la siguiente función requiero que limite el número de resultados devueltos

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.44'}

articles_list = []


def getArticles_Empresas():
    url = 'http://www.businessanddisability.org/es/news-feed/'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'without-video-box'})
    for item in articles:
        article = {
        'Comunidad' : 'Empresa y Discapacidad',
        'Titulos': item.find('h2').text,
        'Links': item.find('a') ['href'],
        'Descripciones': item.find('p').text
        }
        articles_list.append(article)
    return

getArticles_Empresas()


df = pd.DataFrame(articles_list)
df.to_excel('articles.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='Articulos')
print('Fin.')
```

Estoy realizando un web scraping en la página de businessanddisability, me gustaría limitar el número de resultados devueltos a 20, he intentado hacer un for aninado con la función range más sin embargo me devolvió los mismos resultados ¿Qué podría hacer para lograr esto?

Agradezco su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente no declares tu objeto como global, decláralo dentro del **scope** de tu función, de esta forma te permitirá un mejor manejo de los datos, y de esta forma si tienes que usar de nuevo la función, te permitirá obtener los datos de un array limpio en lugar de añadirlos al primer resultado

En vez de

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.44'}

articles_list = []


def getArticles_Empresas():
    ...
    return

getArticles_Empresas()
df = pd.DataFrame(articles_list)
```

Cámbialo a

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.44'}

articles_list = []


def getArticles_Empresas():
    articles_list = []
    ...
    return articles_list

df = pd.DataFrame(getArticles_Empresas())
```

Después podrías obtener el limite no con un for anidado, sino con un for principal

```
 def getArticles_Empresas():
    articles_list = []
    url = 'http://www.businessanddisability.org/es/news-feed/'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'without-video-box'})
    for idx in range(20):
        item = articles[idx]
        article = {
            'Comunidad' : 'Empresa y Discapacidad',
            'Titulos': item.find('h2').text,
            'Links': item.find('a') ['href'],
            'Descripciones': item.find('p').text
        }
        articles_list.append(article)
        
    return articles_list
```

También podrías agregar el límite dentro de la función para hacerlo más escalable

```
def getArticles_Empresas(limit = 20):
    articles_list = []
    url = 'http://www.businessanddisability.org/es/news-feed/'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'without-video-box'})
    for idx in range(limit):
        item = articles[idx]
            article = {
                'Comunidad' : 'Empresa y Discapacidad',
                'Titulos': item.find('h2').text,
                'Links': item.find('a') ['href'],
                'Descripciones': item.find('p').text
            }
            articles_list.append(article)
            
        return articles_list
getArticles_Empresa() # Regresa 20 artículos
getArticles_Empresa(10) # Regresa 10 artículos
df = 
pd.DataFrame(getArticles_Empresa())
df.to_excel('articles.xlsx', index=False, sheet_name='Articulos')
print('Fin.')
```

Comment: Hola!! Agradezco mucho su respuesta, me ha alegrado poder avanzar en lo que quería!!